# How do you reference the origen environment within an Origen 2 document?

Tags: origen-sdk

In the Origen 2 documentation system, how do you reference things like the `dut` and `origen` when building a web document?

For example, I currently have an example code block like this where the version is hardcoded:

```
$ origen -v
Origen: 2.0.0-pre0
```

I would like to make the version a reference to `origen.version`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) and some of the [context provided by default](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/o2/blob/master/python/origen/web/origen_sphinx_extension/templating.py#L65-L99). The entire [origen](https://origen-sdk.org/o2/interbuild/autoapi/origen/origen.html) module is available, so `{{ origen.version }}` in any RST file, but is also not in a `.. raw` block, should do it.

You can stick this in a `code` block as well: ``` ``{{ origen.version }}`` ``` to get something like:

[image]

(this is still using the old styling. It'll update with the new styling when available)

I realize the Jinja context is omitted in the documentation. I opened an ticket on [O2](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/o2/issues/122) to acknowledge some of the documentation lapses.

Thanks!